# Add table runtime in database

Tags: c#

I hav a datatable dt that i am creating at run time now i want to insert this datatable into my database and in my database this table is not existing.I just want to add this table into my database tables collection.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the table in the database by issuing the correct [DML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Manipulation_Language) statements to it.

If you create a command that will create the new table for you, you will then be able to populate it.

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.myNewTable
   id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY (1,1),
   text VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL
```

Without knowing what database and how you are connecting to it, it is difficult to give more detail.

Comment: I have connection string but i do not have a table in database with DataTable dt structure

Answer (score 0):

You need generate SQL script, which will create the table manualy. Something like this:

```
DataTably myTable = GetTable();
var sql = new StringBuilder();
sql.Append( "CREATE TABLE [").Append( myTable.TableName ).AppendLine( "] (");
foreach( DataColumn clm in myTable.Columns ) {
    sql.Append( "[" ).Append( clm.ColumnName ).Append( "] " );
    if ( clm.DataType == typeof( int ) ) { sql.Append( "int" ); }
    else if ( clm.DataType == ... ) { ... }

    ...
}
sql.Append( ")" );
```

Comment: i know this way but I do not want to do this 
i want a table is automatically Inserted/created with my DataTable Structure  in Database without writing Create Command  Is It Possible

Comment: No, the ADO.NET has no automatic way, how to this.